# Unable to set if statement between my code to make it error-free

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I've written a code to set pictures next to it's link in an excel sheet after it's done downloading. It is working smoothly but the problem is that every time i run the code it gets downloaded again and settled there. So if i delete one picture i see another one in that place. I hope there is a solution in if statement so that, if applied, it will omit downloading and go for the next loop if the cell is already filled in. I can't make it. If anybody helps me accomplish this, i would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Note: Links are in B column and pictures to get settled in C column.

```
Sub SetPics()

Dim pics As String
Dim myPic As Picture
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set rng = Range("C2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

    For Each cel In rng
        pics = cel.Offset(0, -1)

        Set myPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pics)    
        With myPic
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = cel.Width
            .Height = cel.Height
            .Top = Rows(cel.Row).Top
            .Left = Columns(cel.Column).Left
        End With    
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scan the `ActiveSheet` (try not to use this, and replace it with `Worksheets("YourSheetName")`) for all Shapes.

For each Shape found, check it's `TopLeftCell.Row` property, if it equals the 
`cel.Row` then the current picture already exists (from previous runs of this code), and you don't "re-insert" the picture.

**Code**

```
Sub SetPics()

Dim pics As String
Dim myPics As Shape
Dim PicExists As Boolean
Dim myPic As Picture
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set rng = Range("C2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

    For Each cel In rng
        PicExists = False ' reset flag
        pics = cel.Offset(0, -1)

        ' loop through all shapes in ActiveSheet
        For Each myPics In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If myPics.TopLeftCell.Row = cel.Row Then  ' check if current shape's row equale the current cell's row
                PicExists = True ' raise flag >> picture exists
                Exit For
            End If
        Next myPics

        If Not PicExists Then '<-- add new picture only if doesn't exist
            Set myPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pics)
            With myPic
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .WIDTH = cel.WIDTH
                .HEIGHT = cel.HEIGHT
                .Top = Rows(cel.Row).Top
                .Left = Columns(cel.Column).Left
            End With
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work, but it's a rather inefficient O(n^2) solution. A better solution would iterate the shapes *once*, store each shape's `Row` in a `Dictionary` key, and then you could have O(1) lookups with `theDictionary.Exists(cel.Row)` instead of iterating every shape for each cell the range.

Comment: Thanks, Shai Rado. You are the gem of a guy. It is flawless now. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear sir Mat's Mug, It would be nice if I had your efficient one too if you have time to spare. Thanks.